# Using individual value from multiple values returned by a function VB.net

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have a function which returns average RGB value of a region drawn on a picturebox in VB.net.

The code is as below:

```
Function GetAvgRGB(ByVal CrdY As Integer, ByVal CrdX As Integer, ByVal Region As System.Drawing.Rectangle) As Tuple(Of Integer, Integer, Integer)

    Dim totalR As UInteger
    Dim totalG As UInteger
    Dim totalB As UInteger

    For y As Integer = CrdY - (Region.Height / 2) To CrdY + ((Region.Height / 2) - 1)
        For x As Integer = CrdX - (Region.Width / 2) To CrdX + ((Region.Width / 2) - 1)
            totalR += myBitmap.GetPixel(x, y).R
            totalG += myBitmap.GetPixel(x, y).G
            totalB += myBitmap.GetPixel(x, y).B
        Next
    Next

    Dim pixelCount As Integer = Region.Width * Region.Height

    Dim averageR As Integer = CType(totalR \ pixelCount, Integer)
    Dim averageG As Integer = CType(totalG \ pixelCount, Integer)
    Dim averageB As Integer = CType(totalB \ pixelCount, Integer)

    Return Tuple.Create(averageR, averageG, averageB)

End Function
```

My query is how do I separate the values of R, G & B returned by this function..

Comment: you mean by using Tuple.Item1, Tuple.Item2 and Tuple.Item3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Item` property.

```
Dim myTuple = GetAvgRGB(?,?,?)
Dim r = myTuple.Item1 ' g = .Item2, b = .Item3
```

Comment: Thank you for a quick resolution !!